# How to reset the HTML5 meter tag

Tags: html, css

I am using the meter element to mark up a rating between 0 and 5 but would prefer to display an image specific for its value rather than the default meter styling:

```
<meter min="0" max="5" value="5">
    <img width="80" height="20" alt="5 out of 5 stars" src="stars_5.png">
</meter>
```

Using appearance none with vendor prefixes seems to have no effect at all in Firefox/Chrome/Safari.

Do I have to resort to putting the image next to it and hiding the meter or is it possible after all?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/html5-meter-element/

Answer (score 0):

I wish there was an easier way but I got it to work by setting the same background image as the img inside the meter tag

Firefox reset (will reset appearance to blank):

```
meter {
    background: none
}

::-moz-meter-bar {
  -moz-appearance: none
}

:-moz-meter-optimum::-moz-meter-bar,
:-moz-meter-sub-optimum::-moz-meter-bar,
:-moz-meter-sub-sub-optimum::-moz-meter-bar {
    background: none
}
```

Chrome/Opera/Safari reset (will reset appearance to blank):

```
meter {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

meter::-webkit-meter-bar,
meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value,
meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value,
meter::-webkit-meter-even-less-good-value,
meter::-webkit-meter-inner-element {
    background: none;
}
```

To replace the meter's appearance with an image per value (good thing I only need it to go from 0 to 5):

```
meter[value='5'] {
    background: url(stars_5.png)
}

meter[value='4'] ... etc
```

I would have preferred a property that would simply display the meter tag as it if were a div.

The only alternative seems to be: Hide the meter tag and display an image next to it..